# Instalar MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Já perguntei antes mas não consegui resolver, dei um tempo, tentei novamente e ainda estou com problemas de iniciar o MongoDB.
Removi ele do meu computador Ubuntu 18.04  e estou instalando novamente me baseando  pela [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) do próprio mongo, depois de instalado quando vou iniciar aparece a seguinte mensagem

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o serviço não existe, então você cria ele

1: Salve o arquivo como **mongodb.service** no seguinte PATH:
**/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service;**

> [Unit]
>
> Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
>
> After=network.target
>
> [Service]
>
> User=mongodb
>
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
>
> [Install]
>
> WantedBy=multi-user.target

2: Tente executar novamente **[sudo] systemctl start mongodb**

Comment: Deu Certo, Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Muito provavelmente a unidade mongodb.service está mascarada. Use o seguinte comando para desmascarar.

```
sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
```

e execute novamente

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: Recebo esta resposta

"Unit mongodb.service does not exist, proceeding anyway."

Comment: Você está digitando no primeiro comando "mongodb" e no segundo "mongod"?

Comment: o primeiro comando

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esse problema eu use estes comandos:

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl status mongod

sudo systemctl enable mongod

sudo systemctl stop mongod

sudo systemctl restart mongod

E voltou a funcionar más depois de reinstalar ele, porem concerteza teria funcionado sem reinstalar